# Setting a useEffect hook's dependency within`useEffect` without triggering useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Edit: It just occurred to me that there's likely no need to reset the variable within the `useEffect` hook. In fact, `stateTheCausesUseEffectToBeInvoked`'s actual value is likely inconsequential. It is, for all intents and purposes, simply a way of triggering `useEffect`.

Let's say I have a functional React component whose state I initialize using the `useEffect` hook. I make a call to  a service. I retrieve some data. I commit that data to state. Cool. Now, let's say I, at a later time, interact with the same service, except that this time, rather than simply retrieving a list of results, I CREATE or DELETE a single result item, thus modifying the entire result set. I now wish to retrieve an updated copy of the list of data I retrieved earlier. At this point, I'd like to again trigger the `useEffect` hook I used to initialize my component's state, because I want to re-render the list, this time accounting for the newly-created result item.

​

```
const myComponent = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = ([])
  useEffect(() => {
    const getSomeData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await callToSomeService()
        setItems(response.data)
        setStateThatCausesUseEffectToBeInvoked(false)
      } catch (error) {
        // Handle error
        console.log(error)
      }
    }
  }, [stateThatCausesUseEffectToBeInvoked])

  const createNewItem = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await callToSomeService()
      setStateThatCausesUseEffectToBeInvoked(true)
    } catch (error) {
        // Handle error
        console.log(error)
    }
  }
}
```

​

I hope the above makes sense.

​

The thing is that I want to reset `stateThatCausesUseEffectToBeInvoked` to `false` WITHOUT forcing a re-render. (Currently, I end up calling the service twice--once for win `stateThatCausesUseEffectToBeInvoked` is set to `true` then again when it is reset to `false` within the context of the `useEffect` hook. This variable exists solely for the purpose of triggering `useEffect` and sparing me the need to elsewhere make the selfsame service request that I make within `useEffect`.

​

Does anyone know how this might be accomplished?

Comment: What is it that you want? You want to re-render the component when you receive new data in order to update it so that it reflects the new data?

Comment: In short, I'd like to re-render the component when a write operation of any sort has occurred--be it a PUT, POST, or a DELETE. Whenever any of these operations occurs, I intend to set `stateThatCausesUseEffectToBeInvoked` to something--anything--just so it triggers `useEffect` to run. This works fine until, except that I also need `useEffect` to clean up after this operation by simply resetting `stateThatCausesUseEffectToBeInvoked` to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you could do to achieve a behavior similar to what you described:

### Change `stateThatCausesUseEffectToBeInvoked` to a number

If you change `stateThatCausesUseEffectToBeInvoked` to a number, you don't need to reset it after use and can just keep incrementing it to trigger the effect.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // ...
}, [stateThatCausesUseEffectToBeInvoked]);

setStateThatCausesUseEffectToBeInvoked(n => n+1); // Trigger useEffect
```

### Add a condition to the `useEffect`

Instead of actually changing any logic outside, you could just adjust your `useEffect`-body to only run if `stateThatCausesUseEffectToBeInvoked` is `true`.
This will still trigger the `useEffect` but jump right out and not cause any unnecessary requests or rerenders.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (stateThatCausesUseEffectToBeInvoked === true) {
    // ...
  }
}, [stateThatCausesUseEffectToBeInvoked]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that 1) by `const [items, setItems] = ([])` you mean `const [items, setItems] = useState([])`, and 2) that you simply want to reflect the latest data after a call to the API:

When the state of the component is updated, it re-renders on it's own. No need for `stateThatCausesUseEffectToBeInvoked`:

```
const myComponent = () => {

const [ items, setItems ] = useState( [] )

const getSomeData = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await callToSomeService1()
        // When response (data) is received, state is updated (setItems)
        // When state is updated, the component re-renders on its own
        setItems( response.data )
    } catch ( error ) {
        console.log( error )
    }
}

useEffect( () => {
    // Call the GET function once ititially, to populate the state (items)
    getSomeData()
    // use [] to run this only on component mount (initially)
}, [] )

const createNewItem = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await callToSomeService2()
        // Call the POST function to create the item
        // When response is received (e.g. is OK), call the GET function
        // to ask for all items again.
        getSomeData()
    } catch ( error ) {
        console.log( error )
    }
}                                           }
```

However, instead of getting all items after every action, you could change your array locally, so if the create (POST) `response.data` is the newly created item, you can add it to `items` (create a new array that includes it).